# magento 1.9 while sending invoice email i wanted to send the track shipment how can i do that

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email-templates, invoice

I have a problem with `Magento 1.9`. I came across functionality where I have to send the `shipping status` when I am sending the `invoice` email to the customer.

How can I add the track shipping functionality in the invoice email?

Thanks in advance.